# Load image for UIImageView in header section view from network

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use `UITableView` and want to display `UIImageView` with loaded image from network in section header. So my method

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` returns next `UIView`:

```
    UIView * header = [UIView new];
    header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    UserDataModel * userData = [CoreDataService sharedInstance].userData;
    UIImageView * userImageView = [UIImageView new];
    userImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, self.view.frame.size.width * 0.3, self.view.frame.size.width * 0.3);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: userData.photoPath]];
        if (data == nil) {

            return;
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            userImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
        });
    });
    [header addSubview:userImageView];
    return header;
```

And it works only after scrolling table view, I can't figure out what I did wrong. Please explain me why it is wrong and how to do it correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: As you said, retrieving the image is asynchronous, don't put it in the viewForHeader, I would suggest you store a reference to the image downloaded, and then reload the table after you get it.

Comment: Use this.. https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage life will be easier

Answer (score 0):

Reload the UIImageView after adding the image.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        userImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
        [userImageView setNeedsDisplay];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) to download it once  as your current code will download it every header appearance

Second create an array of models (imagesUrls) for all header then loop for urls

```
UIImageView*img = [UIImageView new];

for (int section = 0; section < [myArray count]; section++)
{
    MyModel *model = [myArray objectAtIndex:section];

    [img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:model.url] completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {

          [tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:NO];
     }];
}
```